# Change preg_replace url

Tags: php

Sorry for my English bad typing.

I want added tag `<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">`

to bad urls

---

I want (preg_replace) find

`<link rel="canonical" href="/example1/example2/example3/example4" />`

and replace

`<link rel="canonical" href="example1/example2/example3/example4" /><meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">`

This is my code:

```
$body = preg_replace('# <link rel="canonical" href="/example/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)" /> #is', ' <link rel="canonical" href="/example/$1/$2/$3" /><meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">', $body);
```

but this code replace

`<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">`

to all urls.

For example:

> example.com/videos/1234
>   example.com/music/1234
>   example.com/forum

I want just find & replace to 4 id's urls  -  not 3 or 2 id's

Again sorry for my English bad typing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
$body = preg_replace('# <link rel="canonical" href="/example/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)" /> #is', ' <link rel="canonical" href="/example/$1/$2/$3" /><meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">', $body);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't need to use `(.*?)` for every term of the url. It is just enough to check with `.*\/.*\/.*\/.*` if it has 3 slashes. Then you group the hole `<link>` and replace it with `$1<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">`. Your [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) should look like:

```
$body = preg_replace('(<link rel="canonical" href=".*\/.*\/.*\/.*" \/>?)', '$1<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">', $body);
```

A good site to test your regular expressions is [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)